# awk regex column2 equal to a string

Tags: regex, unix, awk

```
cat raw.csv

1,age,AB
2,guage,CD
3,storageblock,AB
4,Agent,CD
5,Change,AB
6,page,CD
```

command:

```
awk -v q="'" --field-separator ',' '(tolower($2) ~ /^age$/) && ($3="Age") {print $1 "," $2 "," $3 }' raw.csv
```

Above command not giving me any output.
Basically question is about output when column 2 is equal to age.

where output supposed to be only:

```
1,age,Age
```

Comment: Why did you edit your expected output with the third column as `Age` and modify the code to test if the third column is `Age`? Is that a new requirement? You did not modify your input with `Age` by the way.

Comment: It is not a good practice to change the requirements in your question again and again. Since you are a new contributor, it is a humble request please take care in future

Comment: @blhsing fyi my input remains no change only output changes here's the requirement -I would also want to update column3 as Age if column2 is equal to age and I would like to use the same regex. why /^age$/ not working in my code

Comment: Plain mismatch between title and question/expected output

Comment: @Mandy8055 - I'm sorry for that

Comment: Voted to close this confusing post

Comment: @GillesQuenot no mistmatch as I'm updating column3 using ($3="Age")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP modified expected output in case you want to change 3rd column then try.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2~/^age$/{$3="Age";print}' Input_file
```

OR

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2)~/^age$/{$3="Age";print}' Input_file
```

---

---

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following with direct condition check and no regex.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2=="age"'  Input_file
```

OR in case OP's Input_file 2nd field could have mix of capital and small letters use tolower with $2.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2)=="age"' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With regex it should be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2~/^age$/' Input_file
```

OR in case OP's Input_file 2nd field could have mix of capital and small letters use `tolower` with $2.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2)~/^age$/' Input_file
```

---

---

***Issue's with OP's approach:*** OP is checking 2nd and 3rd field both are string age or not, which condition never gets satisfied hence it is NOT printing anything. We need to put only 2nd column/field in condition to check so keep only `$2` in condition.

Comment: you are rigtht, I've update my question can you help me with that ?

Comment: is not working for me                                                                  
               awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2)~/^age$/ {print $1 "," $2 "," $3 }' raw.csv

Comment: @Achar007, what you tried is not what I suggested, it is `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} tolower($2)~/^age$/{$3="Age";print}' Input_file` it is.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '$2 ~ /^age$/' file
```

## Output

```
1,age,Age
```